# Python searching for an object by ID prior to insertion into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading several CSV files. I do not have prior knowledge if the files contain duplicate customer information.

```
class customerIdentityCard:
     def __init__(self, id=0, firstName="", lastName=""):
        self.id = id.upper()  # alphanumeric field
        self.firstName = firstName.upper()
        self.lastName = lastName.upper()
```

before I blindly do a:

```
customerList = []

#in my for loop reading data from csv file
customerList.append(customerIdentityCard(field[0],field[1],field[2])
```

I want to check if the customer already exists in my `customerList`.

Since I know each customer has a unique ID number, I don't care if the other fields have spelling errors or other name variations. Just want to be sure that I am not putting duplicate IDs in my list.

Using Python 3.9.5 on Windows.

Comment: That will be very expensive using a list. You'd be better off using a dictionary, and on insertion, make the `customerIdentityCard` the value, and the `id` the key. That said, there isn't really a question here. What have you tried, and what specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I am fairly new to Python. This is my first week! I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Have you used dictionaries yet? If you use a list, you'll need to check the entire list on every insertion. With a dictionary, lookups will be much cheaper.

Comment: If `id` is a number your `__init__` method will fail, for example if no `id` is provided it will take the integer value of `0` and trying to use `.upper()` on that will result in an error

Comment: And I agree with @Carcigenicate, use a dictionary with the `id` as the key and whatever else you want as the values. Quick guide on dictionaries [here](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) if you haven't used them before

Comment: @Carcigenicate I didn't realize what you were saying. Sorry its still early morning in NYC. Morning coffee hasn't kicked in yet! I think you're idea is brilliant! Can I break a dictionary into chunks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a more Pythonic way to prevent adding a duplicate to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834806/is-there-a-more-pythonic-way-to-prevent-adding-a-duplicate-to-a-list)

Comment: How many records do you have? I would suggest a dictionary, as others have, to start. However, if it is very large, then it might make sense to use `pydantic` to create a model for your data. In fact your `customerIdentiferCard` could be simplified to a `pydantic` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a set() to maintain a unique list of ids that have been added already. set() is a little like a list that only contains unique elements but it is also fast to search. As other have suggested, there are also ways to solve this with a `dict` though.

Maybe this to get started with:

```
all_customers = [] ## list from your csv
unique_customers = set()
customerList = []
for customer in all_customers:
    if customer[0] in unique_customers:
        continue
    customerList.append(customerIdentityCard(customer[0],customer[1],customer[2]))
    unique_customers.add(customer[0])
```

Comment: Why not just a dict of `{ID: customer}` instead of maintaining a list ***and*** a set

Comment: @Tomerikoo What would you really gain maintaining the `dict`? You would presumably still check if the item was in the `dict` prior to setting the value for the key. Then after the `dict` was complete one would then go back and use the values to populate `customerList`. The set is cheaper than the dict and you throw both away at the end anyways. If the `dict` completely replaces the `customerList = []` then perhaps it is a better solution. If the poster wants a `list` in the end, the `set` is a better solution